# Why the emulator process has terminated?

Tags: android-studio

I just installed the latest Android Studio (Dolphin) and added an AVD (Pixel 4 API 31).

When launching the emulator, I run into the following error:

```
The emulator process has terminated
```

[image: error]

Here's the log details. I've tried suggestions like making sure the SDK build is at least 30.0.2 (it's 30.0.3), and launching in separate window, invalidating the cache and restarting... nothing helps.

```
2022-11-08 01:49:12,495 [ 296648]   WARN -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. 
2022-11-08 01:49:13,223 [ 297376]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.studio.tooling contents "initscript {\n    dependencies {\n        classpath files(['C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\plugins\\\\android\\\\lib\\\\android.jar', 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\plugins\\\\android\\\\lib\\\\android.jar', 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Android\\\\Android Studio\\\\lib\\\\kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10-release-949.jar'])\n    }\n}\nallprojects {\n    apply plugin: com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin\n}\n" 
2022-11-08 01:49:13,301 [ 297454]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --init-script C:\Users\NUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ijmapper.gradle -Didea.sync.active=true -Didea.resolveSourceSetDependencies=true -Porg.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.cid=6451108675200 --init-script C:\Users\NUser\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling.gradle -Djava.awt.headless=true --stacktrace -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=2021.3.1 Patch 1 -Pandroid.injected.build.model.disable.src.download=true -Pidea.gradle.do.not.build.tasks=true -Dorg.gradle.internal.GradleProjectBuilderOptions=omit_all_tasks -Pkotlin.mpp.enableIntransitiveMetadataConfiguration=true --init-script C:\Users\NUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit.gradle 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,129 [ 298282]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,129 [ 298282]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - IPv4 server found: 192.168.... 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,129 [ 298282]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - IPv6 DNS server found: 2600:1...::1 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,129 [ 298282]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - added library vulkan-1.dll 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,129 [ 298282]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,129 [ 298282]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Sending adb public key [Q...A= @unknown] 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,129 [ 298282]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - injectedQemuChannel! 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,130 [ 298283]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Informing listeners of injection. 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,130 [ 298283]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Rootcanal has  been activated. 
2022-11-08 01:49:14,130 [ 298283]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. 
2022-11-08 01:49:15,260 [ 299413]   INFO - ab.VirtualDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 connected 
2022-11-08 01:49:15,260 [ 299413]   WARN -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.*** 
2022-11-08 01:49:15,261 [ 299414]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none 
2022-11-08 01:49:15,261 [ 299414]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Advertising in: C:\Users\NUser\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_13412.ini 
2022-11-08 01:49:15,331 [ 299484]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - setDisplayConfigs w 1080 h 2280 dpiX 440 dpiY 440 
2022-11-08 01:49:16,450 [ 300603]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-11-08 01:49:16,451 [ 300604]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-11-08 01:49:16,451 [ 300604]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-11-08 01:49:16,451 [ 300604]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-11-08 01:49:16,451 [ 300604]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-11-08 01:49:16,451 [ 300604]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Deleting snapshot default_boot 
2022-11-08 01:49:16,454 [ 300607]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-11-08 01:49:17,442 [ 301595]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Closing down rootcanal. 
2022-11-08 01:49:18,223 [ 302376]   INFO - ab.VirtualDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 disconnected 
2022-11-08 01:49:18,465 [ 302618]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the Pixel4 emulator and created an emulator with following specs:

Pixel 6 API 25
Android 7.1.1 Google APIs | x86 (recommended default)

and that worked...

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved when I changed the ABI setting from "x86_64" to "arm64-v8a"

[image]

Comment: Did you have the same warning `WARN -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - unexpected system image feature string`

Comment: Yes, that's the same error I had!

Comment: `Emulator: Pixel 4 API 30 - PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host`. i figured it out tho, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Do the cold boot of your emulator; no need to reinstall or change any settings. It is possibly the issue when the device doesn't shut down correctly.

[image: 1]